# How to Store Multiple Values Retrieved from database in a list in python

Tags: python-2.7, relational-database

I Have Retrieved values from a  database table in a single list. Now I want it to be separated according to each row. For e.g when I am executing a query for pulling the entire table. The entire data is stored in a single list currently. Now I want it to be separated row by row, so that i can access each row individually. Code Sniplet would be appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: "*Code Sniplet would be appreciated*". Please show what you've done/attempted so far. We're here to help you but not here to spoil you. Also, please post a sample of what type of data your database is returning.

Comment: actually i am new to python, and we are doing a project. I am using MySQl database currently. so when i am using cursor to execute a query and storing the result that are coming from the database in a loop, It is getting stored in a single list. and when printing the list the entire data from the table is pulling. and i want to access only a single row from the table in the table 1 by 1. Sorry for asking the code sniplet.